# json unmarshal not working but decode does

Tags: json, go

I have a hard time understanding why the code below, which uses the unmarshal method does not work, but then almost the same I write with NewDecoder and it works fine.

```
package conf

import (
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Configuration struct {
    Agents []Agent `json:"agents"`
    IbmWmqFolder string `json:"ibmWmqFolder"`
}

type Agent struct {
    AgentName string `json:"agentName"`
    Folders []string `json:"folders"`
}

func LoadConfiguration() (configuration Configuration) {
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("config.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer jsonFile.Close()
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
    json.Unmarshal(byteValue, configuration)
    return
}
```

but if I do all the same but instead of the two last lines with the `byteValue` and the unmarshal itself, but use the decoder, it works,

```
jsonParser := json.NewDecoder(jsonFile)
jsonParser.Decode(&configuration)
return
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that you need to pass a pointer to the configuration, like so:

```
json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &configuration)
```

You should also check the error value returned by Unmarshal, e.g.:

```
err = json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &configuration)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

See the [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal).